# how to make tags within the custom directives go to specific place of template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive by name cngView

```
controller.js 
//directive to include view panel
angular.module('cngFoundation', [])
                                    .directive('cngView', function() {
                                         return {
                                                  restrict : 'CAME',
                                                  templateUrl: 'templates/view.html'
                                                };

                                     });
```

to access directive

```
<div ng-app="cngFoundation">
    <div id="mainbody" class="container">
        <cng-view>  

                 [AAA] 

        </cng-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

The templates/view.html is as  follows

```
<!-- View Panel-->
<div class="panel panel-primary " id="view" >
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title" ><b>View</b></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        [BBB]

    </div>
</div>
```

I have made the cng-view tag work but I don't know how to give contents inside the tag.
How to make contents I give at place "[AAA]" appear at "[BBB]" .
In short how to make contents I give within cng-view tag(a custom tag) go into the specific place inside the template content of the cng-view .

Please give guidance . At least please direct me to some online tutorial .
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ng-transclude` which tells template where to place existing content

```
 <div class="panel-body" ng-transclude></div>
```

Also need to set `transclude:true` in directive

See section [Creating a Directive that Wraps Other Elements](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) in directive docs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in `ng-transclude` directive. In your view.html replace `[BBB]` with

```
<span ng-transclude></span>
```

also be sure to define `transclude` on your directive

```
transclude: true,
```

For a working example see [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZTnr42prR16iGFBLjv5W?p=preview)